# Sending JSON from server requires JSON.parse twice

Tags: javascript, json, go

For some reason I have to call JSON.parse twice to create an object in JavaScript. I'm generating JSON from a Go (Golang) server.

This is the JavaScript code I'm using.

```
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
    console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(e.data)));
};
```

And this is what I saw in Chrome's console.

```
"{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
{"hello":"world"}
Object {hello: "world"}
```

This is how I'm generating JSON on the server side. I suspect my server code is wrong.

```
var jsonBuffer bytes.Buffer

jsonBuffer.WriteString("{")
for key, value := range mydict {
    jsonBuffer.WriteString(`"` + key `":"` + value + `"`)
}
jsonBuffer.WriteString("}")

return jsonBuffer.String()
```

This is a simplification of what I'm working on. In reality, `mydict` is defined as `map[string]mystruct`.

`mystruct` is something like this:

```
type mystruct struct {
    Foo int
    Bar float64
}
```

Comment: Did you set the content type to `application/json`? also anything against using [json.Encoder](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Encoder)?

Comment: Nothing against `json.Encoder`. I'm just a n00b.

Comment: How is the data you described as server side actually sent to the client? The standard Go HTTP code would involve writing the data to an `http.ResponseWriter`, so there must be some more code involved here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you building the json response by hand? I would suggest to use the json package. Your code would look something like this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Mystruct struct {
    Foo int
    Bar float64
}

func main() {
    m := Mystruct{1,100}
    j, _ := json.Marshal(m)
    fmt.Print(string(j))
}
```